# Multiple Dynamic Datetimepicker won't open directly

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

i have a form with multiple dynamically added bootstrap datetimepicker via button click. They all have the same class, so i can open everyone.

The problem is, that i must click multiple times before picker gets open... and if i open one, the other dates in the pickers will be resetted?!

Must i initialize every datetimepicker separately? If yes, on click or onRendered Template helper?

Heres my JS:

```
'click .openDatetimepicker': function(event) {
    $('.speakerDatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L LT',
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'left',
            vertical: 'bottom'
        },
        locale: 'de'
    });
}
```

and HTML

```
{{#each speakerDates}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
        <div class="ten wide column">
           <div class="inline fields">
              <div class="four wide field">
                 <label class="ui orange small header">{{incremented  @index}}. Offtext-Termin</label>
              </div>
               <div class="six wide field">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date speakerDatetimepicker'>
                            <input type="hidden" name="speakerDateID" value="{{this._id}}">
                            <input id="speakerDate{{@index}}" type='text' class="form-control" value="{{start}}" size="14px"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar openDatetimepicker"></span>
                            </span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="one wide field">
                     <button class="ui red medium removeSpeakerDate button" value="{{_id}}">
                         <i class="minus icon"></i>
                     </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
{{/each}}
```

Hope you can help me :-/ Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should initialise datetimepicker and any other jQuery plugins inside onRendered. Also, it makes sense move list item into separate template:

```
<template name="List">
{{#each speakerDates}}
  {{> ListItem}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name='ListItem'>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
        <div class="ten wide column">
           <div class="inline fields">
              <div class="four wide field">
                 <label class="ui orange small header">{{incremented  @index}}. Offtext-Termin</label>
              </div>
               <div class="six wide field">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date speakerDatetimepicker'>
                            <input type="hidden" name="speakerDateID" value="{{this._id}}">
                            <input id="speakerDate{{@index}}" type='text' class="form-control" value="{{start}}" size="14px"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar openDatetimepicker"></span>
                            </span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="one wide field">
                     <button class="ui red medium removeSpeakerDate button" value="{{_id}}">
                         <i class="minus icon"></i>
                     </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

And JS:

```
Template.ListItem.onRendered(function(){
// notice this before $: we initializing datetime picker
// only inside current list item template.
   this.$('.speakerDatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L LT',
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'left',
            vertical: 'bottom'
        },
        locale: 'de'
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, works almost well, but now my @index is broken and i get an error: unsupported directive... any solution?

Comment: @DennisB Passing it directly into template should help: `{{> ListItem index=@index listItem=this}}`. Also, notice while using it your context inside `ListItem` template is going to change a bit. But you can always use `#with` and `../` to get data you need.

Comment: thanks i got the index now with {{speakerdate index=@index}} but now i must solve the next problem: the dynamically added datetimepicker shows a random date like "0004-04-06 00:00" when i open it... The defaultDate option has no effect